# Uses Expo start instead of npm start

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I am currently learning React Native. For past few days i have used `npm start` to run the app on my device by scanning the generated QR code.

Suddenly the terminal requested me to install `EXPO CLI`. I thought it was a bug and proceed with the installation. However, after the installation, every time i run `npm start` the terminal runs `expo start` instead and opens up a new tab on my browser called `Metro Bundler`. May I know how to reverse the process as now the app is not able to run using expo start. Keep displaying errors.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly the same problem i faced. Fixed it by creating a new react native project from instructions [here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app), according to which its a new update and Create React Native App has been merged with Expo CLI.

Comment: ya, i think it was a new version of expo CLI that causes this issue. However, i have encounter problem running the app when imported 'Stack Navigator'. However, its another problem, thanks

Comment: expo cli has been deprecated